# C# UWP Carousel Focus Animation

Tags: c#, animation, uwp, focus, carousel

As first sorry for my bad english. I have a Carousel View that works really well.

```
` <my:Carousel x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="Carousel" IsDoubleTapEnabled="False"  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ces}}" Margin="21,730,33,37" ItemMargin="20" ItemDepth="200" ItemRotationX="0" ItemRotationY="0" ItemRotationZ="0" InvertPositive="False" PointerPressed="Carousel_PointerPressed" SelectionChanged="Carousel_SelectionChanged" ManipulationStarted="Carousel_ManipulationStarted" >
            <my:Carousel.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Bilder">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <Image Width="250" Height="170" Source="{Binding Bild}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </my:Carousel.ItemTemplate>
         </my:Carousel>`
```

I want to remove the border if a item getting and loosing focus (see picture below). How can I manage this? I know there is something with a Storyboard, but i dont know how to use it.

Please help me.

[image: enter Getting Focus Border / Loosing Focus Border]

Comment: It is possible to use a negativ padding in you image?

Comment: I cant use padding for images. I tried it with Margin but it dont influence the animation effect.

Comment: In your above xaml code, there seems no a border, where does the border come?

Comment: The border came from the Animation loosing focus / getting focus and is only visible if i change a item.

Comment: @Hubii Do you want to implement the effect that the selected item has a border while the other items without borders?

Comment: in my Carousel are 7 items. The other 5 items has no border. It only happend if the item loosing and getting Focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind the `Model` (here should be your `Bilder` class)'s property to the border's background, after that, when you select an item, the Model's corresponding property will change and the Border will also change with the property's changing. The `Model`/`Bilder` class should implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.inotifypropertychanged) interface. The following is a simple example.

Firstly, add a `borderBrush` property in your `Bilder` class and implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.inotifypropertychanged) interface.

```
public class Bilder : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Bild { get; set; }
    private SolidColorBrush borderBrush;
    public SolidColorBrush BorderColor
    {
        get { return borderBrush; }
        set
        {
            borderBrush = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BorderColor));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

Secondly, modify the `Carousel.ItemTemplate` to add a border,

```
<my:Carousel.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" BorderBrush="{Binding BorderColor}"
                    BorderThickness="2">
                <Image Width="250" Height="170" Source="{Binding Bild}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</my:Carousel.ItemTemplate>
```

Then you can operate the `Carousel_SelectionChanged` to change the corresponding item's property to make the items with border. When you initialize the `Bilder` object, you maybe need to set the default `BorderColor` property to `Colors.Transparent`.

Here is the Page.xaml.cs code with `Carousel_SelectionChanged` event handler,

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
    OperateItems = new List<Bilder>();
}

List<Bilder> OperateItems;

private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //these two lines code could be deleted if you don't set the default selected item
    Carousel.SelectedIndex = 0;
    ((Bilder)Carousel.SelectedItem).BorderColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);
}

private void Carousel_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    OperateItems.Clear();
    foreach (Bilder item in e.AddedItems)
    {
        OperateItems.Add(item);
    }
    foreach (Bilder item in e.RemovedItems)
    {
        OperateItems.Add(item);
    }

    foreach (Bilder item in Carousel.Items)
    {
        if (OperateItems.Contains(item))
        {
            item.BorderColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);
        }
        else
        {
            item.BorderColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This one does not work for me. I know there is something with a Storyboard im XML. But i dont know how to use it right.

Answer (score 0):

Atleast i slove my Problem. My Pictures was to big. The border came from Size down the Picture. I found a Code with that u does not loose any Quality by sizing

```
public static BitmapImage ResizedImage(BitmapImage sourceImage, int maxWidth, int maxHeight)
    {
        var origHeight = sourceImage.PixelHeight;
        var origWidth = sourceImage.PixelWidth;
        var ratioX = maxWidth / (float)origWidth;
        var ratioY = maxHeight / (float)origHeight;
        var ratio = Math.Min(ratioX, ratioY);
        var newHeight = (int)(origHeight * ratio);
        var newWidth = (int)(origWidth * ratio);

        sourceImage.DecodePixelWidth = newWidth;
        sourceImage.DecodePixelHeight = newHeight;

        return sourceImage;
    }
```